# Grails 'Cannot issue a redirect' Issue

Tags: grails

The following issue is happening:

```
def someAction() {
    ...
    if (someCondition)
        redirect action: 'index'
        return
    }

    if (someOtherCondition)
        redirect action: 'index'
        return
    }

    ...

    redirect action: 'success'
}
```

This works perfectly. But as soon as I wrap this in a transaction:

```
def someAction() {
    MyDomainClass.withTransaction { status ->

        if (someCondition)
            status.setRollbackOnly()
            redirect action: 'index'
            return
        }

        if (someOtherCondition)
            status.setRollbackOnly()
            redirect action: 'index'
            return
        }

        ...

    }

    redirect action: 'success'
}
```

This causes an exception to be thrown:

> > Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. The response has already been committed either by another redirect or by directly writing to the response.. Stacktrace follows:
> >     Message: Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. The response has already been committed either by another redirect or by directly writing to the response.

The strange thing is I've done exactly the same in another piece of the code and it works perfectly. The only difference is that I am chaining rather than redirecting. I have tried chaining in the code above, but it still throws the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `return` from:

```
MyDomainClass.withTransaction { status ->

        if (someCondition)
            status.setRollbackOnly()
            redirect action: 'index'
            return   //   <-- !!! this one !!!
        }
}
```

is returning you from closure block, not from action. So it calls `redirect action: 'index'`, exit from closure, and execute block after, with another redirect:

```
redirect action: 'success'
```

Last one causes this exception.

As a workaround you can remember redirect state and check on last step, like:

```
boolean redirected = false
MyDomainClass.withTransaction { status ->

        if (someCondition)
            status.setRollbackOnly()
            redirected = true
            redirect action: 'index'
            return
        }
}
if (!redirected) { 
    redirect action: 'success'
}
```

or just check that response is not commited yet (but this way seems little bit hacky):

```
if (!response.commited) {
    redirect action: 'success'
}
```

Comment: Yeah that makes 100% sense. In the other code that I am doing something similar I am first creating a list of issues before returning. Thanks!